# Trying to create a "provider" in scala using generics

Tags: scala, generics, provider

i am trying to create a provider class in scala that will return the correct object when called

trait

```
trait RemoteValidator[A <:Widget]{
def processRemoteValidation(request: EventRequest[_], widget: A):     Future[Seq[Widget]]
}
```

class extending trait

```
class ResourceInstanceListRemoteValidator @Inject() extends RemoteValidator[InstanceListWidget[InstanceWidget]] {

  override def processRemoteValidation(request: EventRequest[_], widget: InstanceListWidget[InstanceWidget]): Future[Seq[Widget]] = {
     //stuff
  }
```

provider

```
class RemoteValidatorProvider[T] @Inject()(resourceInstanceListRemoteValidator: ResourceInstanceListRemoteValidator) {
 val validators = Map("resources" -> resourceInstanceListRemoteValidator)
 def getRemoteValidator(key: String): Option[RemoteValidator] = {
 validators.get(key)
 }
}
```

the issuse is when i call provider.processRemoteValidation(request, instanceListWidget) i get "Type mismatch expected type A, actual InstanceListWidget[InstanceWidget]. I know this would work in java, but i am not too familiar with generics in scala, what should i be doing instead?

Comment: There's definitely some code missing here. If I just drop ??? as the implementation of `ResourceInstanceListRemoteValidator.processRemoteValidation` and call it the only error I get is the unimplemented exception from the ???. 
RemoteValidatorProvider doesn't have a processRemoteValidation method. Please go back over the code snippets and make sure there is enough there to reproduce your problem

Comment: The return type of `RemoteValidatorProvider.getRemoteValidator` is invalid (this should not actually compile at all): `RemoteValidator` needs a type parameter. Fix it first, then see if it solves your problem. If not, post the updated code.